# How do I assign user input into categories based on whether its equal to a value in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, user-input

So I'm making a program that will create a grocery list for the user. It will start up, introduce itself, and prompt you to enter your items. After you enter the items it will sort them into categories such as "Dairy" "Dry Goods", that is the part I am struggling with

```
Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("[<I-I-I-I-I>] LOADING [<I-I-I-I-I>]");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("Initiating GROCERMAN. . .");
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to GROCERMAN! GrocerMan will help you create the best grocery list ever.");
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the items you would like to purchase:");
string purchInp = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine($"Are you sure you want to buy these items: {purchInp}? Please enter 'Yes' or 'No' exactly or it will not register.");
var decbuy = Console.ReadLine();
if(decbuy == "Yes"){
Console.WriteLine("Awesome! Please wait one moment.");
Console.WriteLine("Alright, I made your list! Here it is:");
Console.WriteLine(purchInp);
}
else if(decbuy == "No"){
Console.WriteLine("Ah, very well. You can restart the program to make a new list or you could leave, I guess. . .");
}
Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
```

I have no clue how to take the `purchInp` and read through it and automatically assign it to a category. I thought that I could compare it to arrays that include as many possibilities of an item (i.e. an array full of all possible dairy items) and if it matches an item in a certain array (like you enter "Milk" and that matches with "Milk" in the Dairy array and prints it under the headline "Dairy".) and sort it out that way but I am not sure how to do that.
It would print it out ideally like so:

[dairy]

Milk

Cheese

[Dry Goods]

Cereal

Bread

etc. . . .

I dont know how to do those linebreaks while printing it either, I saw you could do an empty `Console.WriteLine();` but seeing as its printing out an entire brick of data-- with printing out `purchInp` I cant see how it would work.

Comment: IMHO the answer depends on how your input will look like? So what do you expect does the user enters? are products seperated by `;` eg. `"Milk;Bread;"`? does a user need to input the category himself with a suffix of `:` eg. `"Dairy:Milk;DryGoods:Bread;"`

Comment: once you have defined the input it is a matter of string manipulation eg. spliting the string by `;`

Comment: Well it would be entered just as a sentence style list like : Olives, Oranges, Milk, Cheese etc. The string they input would be saved to the purchInp variable and then it is compared to all arrays that I make like Dairy and Dry-Goods etc and if it finds that Milk in the string equals milk in the array it will--when the entire thing prints-- put it under pregenerated categories. So I enter "milk" in the program and it will return to me with " Categories: Dairy [Milk]. It seems like it should be simple but I just cant figure it out

Comment: Also I know what you mean with string manipulation but how would I manipulate the value of purchInp? They enter their items in a string, string is saved to variable, then variable is sorted to categories and printed. I am not sure where you would be able to edit it to add the linebreaks.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0lifLJ

Comment: Alrighty. I will check it out.

Comment: Please indent your sample code so it is readable. The auto formating tools in your IDE can help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tools you could use:

1. For readability use indentation :)
2. For better comparisions compare `ToLower()` so 'Yes' and 'yes' both match
3. For splitting a string: `List<string> items = purchInp.Split(",");`
4. For printing in different lines `foreach(var item in items) { Console.WriteLine(item) };`
5. For storing categories use a new class or a collection: `var knownItems = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>(); knownItems.Add("Diary", new List<string>() { "Milk", "Cream" });`

Comment: Thanks! I will have to put these into use.